# SQL to Fetch records in period between every 15 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 lakhs of data in my database,need to fetch record based on 'uploaddatetime'
(Column in database)of every 15 days.For example,

```
Date               Number of Records.
April 1st-15th            20
April 16th-30th           40
May 1st to 15th           1000
May 16th to 31st          4000
```

Till date,have any idea to fetch data using Microsoft SQL-2008 R2

Comment: How exactly you want to distinguish among these different different output?
Means How you want to see that first output Apr1st-15th finished and second output came?

Comment: Hi Radu Gheorghiu,
I need to display records based on the 'uploadatetime' column as below.For example:Apr 1st-15th 'Number of record',Apr 16th-30th 'Number of record'

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
select 
case 
when date_col>='20130401' and date_col<'20130416' then 'April 1st-15th'
when date_col>='20130416' and date_col<'20130501' then 'April 16th-30th'
.
.
as date_range
end
count(*) as total
from table
group by 
when date_col>='20130401' and date_col<'20130416' then 'April 1st-15th'
when date_col>='20130416' and date_col<'20130501' then 'April 16th-30th'
.
.
end
```

Comment: True, but not very efficient if you want to go, let's say over 2 years of data.